# doctrine2 get rows from mapping table

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to get the mapping table associated ids.

mapping_table

```
id service_receiver_id service_provider_id
1  1                      2
2  4                      1
```

How can i write the doctrine query for retrieving 1 mapped to...

i need the results like,

```
associated_with
2
4
```

In my case i have using this query:

```
$qb->select('om', 'o', 'ot')
                ->from('Organization\Entity\OrgMapping', 'om')
                ->leftJoin('om.organization', 'o')
                ->where('om.organization = :hspId')
                ->setParameter('hspId', $hspId);
```

above query result only

```
//List of Associates that is Mapped Already
$organizations = $this->orgMappingRepository->listAssociatesByHSPId($hspId, $mapType, $filterBy, $searchBy, $pageNo, $paginationArr);

$mappedAssociates = array();
foreach ($organizations as $org) {
    $mappedAssociates[$org->getServiceProvider()->getId()] = array(
        'id' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getId(),
        'name' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getName(),
        'orgType' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getOrgType()->getName(),
        'logo' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getLogo(),
        'cityName' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getCity() ? $org->getServiceProvider()->getCity()->getName() : null,
        'areaName' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getArea() ? $org->getServiceProvider()->getArea()->getName() : null,
        'zipcode' => $org->getServiceProvider()->getZipcode(),
    );
}

the result i am getting is :

 id service_receiver_id service_provider_id
    1  1                      2
```

Comment: It is recursive, right?

Comment: @goto yes, its recursive